# How to set the dns option in Azure web app for containers

Tags: azure, docker, containers, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

This is what happens to run the container. I wonder if there is a way to start the web app for containers with a custom DNS.

I have 5 microservices in my ILB-ASE
they need to be able to call each other using my custom DNS server in the VNet. When I check the resolv.conf i see 127.0.0.11. I need that to be set to my own custom dns server.

**how can we inject my custom DNS value here?**

Should we use the `appsettings` if so what are the values in the web app for containers?

*So I can use the --dns option*

The mystery part that Azure runs it. Some values are coming up from the appsettings.

> 2018-08-23 14:12:56.100 INFO - docker run -d -p 13940:5001 --name xxx
>   -e DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME=xxx.azurecr.io/xxx:558 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=5001 -e
>   WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=xxx -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e
>   WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=xxx -e
>   HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 xxx.azurecr.io/xxx:558
>
> =====DOCKER LOG=========
>
> 2018_08_23_RD0003FF2D0408_default_docker.log:
>
> ​
>
> 2018-08-23T14:12:49.755843301Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
>
> 2018-08-23T14:12:49.755897801Z No XML encryptor configured. Key
>   {xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
>
> 2018-08-23T14:12:54.761216323Z [40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>
> 2018-08-23T14:12:54.761251623Z Overriding address(es) 'http://+:80'.
>   Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
>
> 2018-08-23T14:12:54.908189021Z Hosting environment: Production
>
> 2018-08-23T14:12:54.908386123Z Content root path: /app
>
> 2018-08-23T14:12:54.908961927Z Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5001
>
> 2018-08-23T14:12:54.909256229Z Application started. Press Ctrl+C to
>   shut down.
>
> ​
>
> 2018_08_23_RD0003FF2D0408_docker.log:
>
> 2018-08-23 14:12:44.125 INFO - Recycling container because of
>   AppFrameworkVersionChange and appFrameworkVersion = xxx.xxx.io/xxx:558
>
> 2018-08-23 14:12:45.900 INFO - Starting container for site
>
> 2018-08-23 14:12:45.900 INFO - docker run -d -p 30464:5001 --name xxx
>   -e DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME=xxx.azurecr.io/xxx:549 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=5001 -e
>   WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=xxx -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e
>   WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=xxx -e
>   HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 xxx.xxx.io/xxx:558
>
> ​
>
> 2018-08-23 14:12:55.972 INFO - Container xxx for site xxx initialized
>   successfully.
>
> 2018-08-23 14:12:55.976 INFO - Recycling container because of
>   AppSettingsChange and isMainSite = True
>
> 2018-08-23 14:12:56.099 INFO - Starting container for site
>
> 2018-08-23 14:12:56.100 INFO - docker run -d -p 13940:5001 --name xxx
>   -e DOCKER_CUSTOM_IMAGE_NAME=xxx.azurecr.io/xxx:558 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=5001 -e
>   WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=xxx -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e
>   WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=xxx -e
>   HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 xxx.azurecr.io/xxx:558
>
> 2018-08-23 14:13:05.385 INFO - Container xxx for site xxx initialized
>   successfully.

​

Comment: Do you want to [map your custom DNS name to your current web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)?

Comment: nope I need to be able to set the DNS of the app service plan. So my microservices can call to each other

Comment: I'm getting downvoted for some reason, but I'm pretty sure that Service Discovery is the best solution for Microservices. It's an industry standard already stablished. Did you give a try? I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we responded to your question on Github and Reddit. Re-posting our response  here for visibility.

"Currently, there is a workaround for this: you should modify the default resolv.conf to the custom DNS IP and then add your custom resolv.conf on docker build by adding a COPY command in your entrypoint script and pointing a custom resolv.conf to /etc.

However, we are investigating a better solution for this, so that manually updating the resolv.conf wouldn’t be necessary, so stay tuned."

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use DNS to communicate with microservices, instead, you should make use of [service registry](https://microservices.io/patterns/service-registry.html).

Check this [Microsoft paper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/microservices-addressability-service-registry) talking about this:

> Each microservice has a unique name (URL) that is used to resolve its
>   location. Your microservice needs to be addressable wherever it is
>   running. If you have to think about which computer is running a
>   particular microservice, things can go bad quickly. In the same way
>   that DNS resolves a URL to a particular computer, your microservice
>   needs to have a unique name so that its current location is
>   discoverable. Microservices need addressable names that make them
>   independent from the infrastructure that they are running on. This
>   implies that there is an interaction between how your service is
>   deployed and how it is discovered, because there needs to be a service
>   registry. In the same vein, when a computer fails, the registry
>   service must be able to indicate where the service is now running.

As you can see, the best solution will depend on your deployment model. Check this note about containers:

> In some microservice deployment environments (called clusters, to be
>   covered in a later section), service discovery is built-in. For
>   example, within an Azure Container Service environment, **Kubernetes and
>   DC/OS with Marathon can handle service instance registration and
>   deregistration**. They also run a proxy on each cluster host that plays
>   the role of server-side discovery router. Another example is Azure
>   Service Fabric, which also provides a service registry through its
>   out-of-the-box Naming Service.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer. @the registry service must be able to indicate where the service is now running.@ We did not have a budget for this. How do you compare Marathon with Consul ?